# jQuery plugin: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery plugin called "spriteOnHover". I read all answered questions about this error and followed all steps explained. But I am still getting same error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined"

Plugin link: [here](http://apolinariopassos.com.br/dev/sprite-on-hover-jquery-plugin/)

Line of error is:

```
var path = $(this).css('background-image').replace('url', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post more code. The HTML and the CSS - we need to see that there is a background image, and what `$(this)` is, or observe that either is missing.

Comment: Also you may find this useful `.match(/(url\(['"]?([^)])['"]?\))/i);`

Comment: "we need to see that there is a background image" One of them was mising! Thank you so much @Popnoodles !